If a web page loads without www or with it depending on link or typed does that dilute search rank?
An SEO engine crawled our site and displayed pages twice, so like https://site.com and https://www.site.com.
Should we set IIS to always or never show www, or is it irrelevant? Also, if we did, would that not also be a potential minus as its a redirect?

From an SEO perspective, there isn't really any impact on www vs. non-www.
The only thing you need to make sure is you are only using one and you are properly redirecting traffic to one.
This will ensure Google (and other engines) are only indexing one site rather than www and non-www.
I would also recommend you verify your canonicals are properly setup and pointing to the correct version as well.

The issue was in IIS where in some cases the pages would load as "https://domain.com/whatever/" and fixed web.config syntax to add the www before the domain.
A bunch of SEO sites (takes out grain of salt) say it does affect search as it's not what's in links in, say, menus or sitemap.  And it's not broken, but not correct or canonical. Anyway, moot with fix in web.config.

As mentioned in another response, for SEO, it doesn't really matter which URL is used — they will carry the same weight.
However, having both versions indexed dilutes the domain authority across the two URLs.
Choose the version that is more convenient for you and set up redirects from the other version using a 301 redirect.
After that, make sure to consistently use the selected version everywhere, including in external links.

Do you have any evidence for your statement "However, having both versions indexed dilutes the domain authority across the two URLs."     Certainly there is strong evidence Google does not have a duplicate content penalty - although I accept your claim was to do with DA, not duplicate content.

@Evgeny Yudin
Thanks, please see my comment above to A_Patterson.

@davidgo
If I had "evidence" of anything about how Google does it's thing I could write a book and make a mint ;).

@skidd I was asking the question of the person that answered as I am not sure its correct (it could be though). There are sources if evidence for SEO - Google has people that make statements, and SEO specialists run tests.  Answers should be backed by fact. If its opinion it should be marked as such or a comment!
